# Computing vector linear regression

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, linear-regression

In eye tracking we have to compute the linear regression for pupil and gaze. The formula is: $$\begin{bmatrix} gaze_x \\ gaze_y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \theta_1 \\ \theta_2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \theta_3 \\ \theta_4 \end{bmatrix}.pupil_x + \begin{bmatrix} \theta_5 \\ \theta_6 \end{bmatrix}.pupil_y $$
which I have written in form of: $gaze_x = \theta_1 + \theta_3.pupilx + \theta5.pupil_y$ and $gaze_y = \theta_2 + \theta_4.pupil_x + \theta_6.pupil_y$
 There are now two questions. first is my decomposition correct? secondly $pupil_y$ and $pupil_x$ have seven values and they are equal which makes the program that computes the theta values to produce a singular vector value error. what should be done in this case?

Comment: So, to see if I understand correctly: $pupil_x$ stands for $pupil_1$ and $pupil_y$ for $pupil_2$ (right and left). This is only to avoid unnecessary notation like $x,y$. Next: the value of pupil_x=pupil_y for all your seven patients?

Comment: @Stef yes that is correct I can even add the values for all variables

Comment: So, simplify things: Define $X=pupil_1+pupil_2$ and $Y=gaze$. Your model becomes $Y=θ_0+θ_1Χ$. Now you say that you have $n=7$ measurements and all of them have exactly the same values?

Comment: @Stef only the values for pupils are the same, the values for the gazes are different. yes n = 7

Comment: You cannot perform regression if all values of $X$ are the same. So, you say, that for the same value of $X$ you get different values for $Y$. And moreover that you only have one single value for $X$. You cannot do regression with this data.

Comment: @Stef So the data is incorrect

Comment: It is not enough to perform regression. Do not say "incorrect", this is something else.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the question was wrong. One assumption was added that stated $theta_4 = 0 $ and $theta_5 = 0 $. Then it is possible to do linear regression.